# Firefox specific margin?

Tags: css, firefox, margin

How can I set a specific margin for Firefox in CSS? I tried -moz-margin:0px;

My problem is in every browser, even IE works,

but firefox fails at my CSS now... There are certain links that move like 1px to the left when I rollover them...

Comment: Can you provide an example page? I've not had this issue on any of the new versions of Firefox.

Comment: It's a local instance - but it the links do have a padding of 5px; around them, and margin of 6px;...

Comment: If they move 1px to the left when you rollover them make sure the :hover css selectors are the same as the non hover. Also open up firebug and rollover them and see what changes.

Comment: I actually just fixed it - :) There was something using em as measurement and FF fails at Em..

Comment: @Matt, if you are able to add code examples to your question, and your own answer for the fix, then this question would be useful to other folks.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Your problem probably lies elsewhere, but here's how you target Firefox only:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    a {
        margin: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro for sharing it!

Answer (score 20):

You can try something like this:

`@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    //Your css here
}`

That will only be read by Firefox.

[Source](http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/browser-specific_css_hacks/#Safari)

Answer (score 9):

To directly answer your question:

```
.myElement, x:-moz-any-link, x:default {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

This will set all elements with the 'myElement' class to a 0px margin within firefox only.