# Inconsistent margin/padding around text with a border between Firefox and Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, margin, text-rendering

Take the following example:

```css
span {
  color: blue;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  font: 9px Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<span>LOREM IPSUM</span>
<span>LOREM IPSUM</span>
<span>LOREM IPSUM</span>
<span>LOREM IPSUM</span>
```

Browsers will add some inconsistent margins/paddings between the border and the text:

**Firefox:**

- 2px top and bottom
- 1px left
- 0px right

**Chrome:**

- 1px left, top and right
- 2px bottom

Resetting `margin` and/or `padding` to 0 does nothing. Is there anyway to get this more **consistent** between browsers? Preferably, with all sides having the same margin?

Comment: Do a browser check and set the margins explicitly.

Comment: @machnaimh Not sure what you mean. I'm not adding any margins at all, those are added by the browsers. Even if I reset them (both `margin` and `padding`), those margins will still be there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6737175/firefox-specific-margin

Comment: @machnaimh Chrome is more problematic than Firefox.

Answer (score -1):

You could try using different prefixes like below for example:

```
.someDiv {
   height: 19px; // probably your code
   -webkit-height:19px; // for chrome and safari
   -o-height:19px; // for opera
   -moz-height:19px; // for firefox
}
```