# Hide Scroll in Modal ONLY but still scrollable inside the modal

Tags: jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

I'm creating a modal that has lots of info in it, I wanted to hide the scollbar  in the MODAL only, not in the body but still scrollable in the modal.

I've tried

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
    background: transparent;
}
```

But it also hides the scollbar in the body.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style='overflow-y: scroll; height:350px;'>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum aliquam ac sem vitae pretium. Nam cursus nisl vitae ex sodales pellentesque. Fusce in accumsan nibh, blandit aliquam felis. Curabitur elementum ac ex sed iaculis. Aliquam vel hendrerit orci, at blandit metus. Maecenas semper erat velit, nec efficitur augue accumsan in. In sed eros vitae arcu aliquam accumsan in eget nibh. Integer sapien tortor, fringilla at augue a, posuere aliquam augue. Donec vestibulum vestibulum ex ac vulputate. Nam interdum sagittis leo, non consequat nisl convallis ut. In urna ex, porta in placerat vel, volutpat in est. Ut ornare tempor semper. Praesent ipsum lacus, viverra ac arcu ac, commodo tristique velit.</p><br>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum aliquam ac sem vitae pretium. Nam cursus nisl vitae ex sodales pellentesque. Fusce in accumsan nibh, blandit aliquam felis. Curabitur elementum ac ex sed iaculis. Aliquam vel hendrerit orci, at blandit metus. Maecenas semper erat velit, nec efficitur augue accumsan in. In sed eros vitae arcu aliquam accumsan in eget nibh. Integer sapien tortor, fringilla at augue a, posuere aliquam augue. Donec vestibulum vestibulum ex ac vulputate. Nam interdum sagittis leo, non consequat nisl convallis ut. In urna ex, porta in placerat vel, volutpat in est. Ut ornare tempor semper. Praesent ipsum lacus, viverra ac arcu ac, commodo tristique velit.</p><br>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

this is the JS Fiddel http://jsfiddle.net/tLrmb5a8/

I expect to hide the scroll INSIDE the modal only.

Comment: Hi, there is not scrollbar for the modal. scrollbar that is coming is of body. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this is what you're looking for:

```
.modal-body{
  height:300px;
  overflow-y:auto;
}

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
   /*firefox*/
   .modal-content {
    overflow: hidden;
   }
   .modal-body{
     margin-right: -16px;
     overflow-y: scroll;
     overflow-x: hidden;
   }
}

.modal-body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
    background: transparent;
}
```

[JsFiddle Fork](http://jsfiddle.net/vdb2134z/1/) or Snippet:

```css
.modal-body{
  height:300px;
  overflow-y:auto;
}

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
   /*firefox*/
   .modal-content {
    overflow: hidden;
   }
   .modal-body{
     margin-right: -16px;
     overflow-y: scroll;
     overflow-x: hidden;
   }
}

.modal-body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
    background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum aliquam ac sem vitae pretium. Nam cursus nisl vitae ex sodales pellentesque. Fusce in accumsan nibh, blandit aliquam felis. Curabitur elementum ac ex sed iaculis. Aliquam vel hendrerit orci, at blandit metus. Maecenas semper erat velit, nec efficitur augue accumsan in. In sed eros vitae arcu aliquam accumsan in eget nibh. Integer sapien tortor, fringilla at augue a, posuere aliquam augue. Donec vestibulum vestibulum ex ac vulputate. Nam interdum sagittis leo, non consequat nisl convallis ut. In urna ex, porta in placerat vel, volutpat in est. Ut ornare tempor semper. Praesent ipsum lacus, viverra ac arcu ac, commodo tristique velit.</p><br>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum aliquam ac sem vitae pretium. Nam cursus nisl vitae ex sodales pellentesque. Fusce in accumsan nibh, blandit aliquam felis. Curabitur elementum ac ex sed iaculis. Aliquam vel hendrerit orci, at blandit metus. Maecenas semper erat velit, nec efficitur augue accumsan in. In sed eros vitae arcu aliquam accumsan in eget nibh. Integer sapien tortor, fringilla at augue a, posuere aliquam augue. Donec vestibulum vestibulum ex ac vulputate. Nam interdum sagittis leo, non consequat nisl convallis ut. In urna ex, porta in placerat vel, volutpat in est. Ut ornare tempor semper. Praesent ipsum lacus, viverra ac arcu ac, commodo tristique velit.</p><br>
          
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Courtesy for [Firefox scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15672455/3654837) and [Firefox specific margin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6737272/3654837)

Comment: @KoshVery updated and tested in Firefox :) thanks for notifying cross-browser issue